# How to create a signup form in a popup in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I was willing to place a popup for a signup form just like a dialog fragment in the xamarin android.
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/fragments/part_3_-_specialized_fragment_classes/

I had spent much time researching for this but failed to create one. My intension is to take the input from the popup created and hit a API in the background showing the loader and in success i like to close the loader and the popup used to take data from the user. Can any one help me out doing this in xamarin forms.

Comment: Refer to this : https://www.onthefencedevelopment.com/creating-a-simple-modal-dialog-form-for-xamarinforms/

Answer (score 1):

Use Rg plugins popup, link for reference https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup